# How to extract data from a snowflake table into CSV using Python

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
import snowflake.connector
import sys
import logging
import logging.config

class opMetadataExt:
def __init__(self):
    #self.logger = logging.getLogger('csv_to_json')
    self.sfExtract()

def sfExtract(self):

    #pwd = input("Password: ")

    sqlSnowflake = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=
        password=
        account=
        database=
        role=
        warehouse=
        #warehouse=
        schema=
    )

    sqlSnowflake.cursor().execute("USE WAREHOUSE ")
    sqlSnowflake.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE ")
    sqlSnowflake = sqlSnowflake.cursor()
   
    test = "copy into '@/extractFile/' from (select * from information_schema.tables limit 1) file_format=(format_name=(type='csv'))"

    try:
        sqlSnowflake.execute(test)
        rows = sqlSnowflake.fetchall()            print(f'Data - {rows}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        #sqlSnowflake.rollback()
    finally:
        sqlSnowflake.close()
```

But getting the below error:

```
001012 (42601): 0195a241-01fd-1365-0000-54ad01f956da: SQL compilation error:
missing stage name in URL: @/extractFile/
```

Comment: I don't think your stage is correct.  Try using `@extractFile/` instead of `@/extractFile/`.  There shouldn't be a slash after the @.  I am assuming you have a stage name `extractFile`

Comment: Try print your unload copy command and execute in snowflake webUI to check copy command is correct..

Comment: I haven’t created any stage name in snowflake, can you let me know how to create one.

Comment: you can create a stage using - create or replace stage <stage_name> command.